# OpenGL: "Fragment Shader not supported by HW" on old ATI card

Tags: opengl, glsl

In our OpenGL game we've got a shader link failure on an ATI Radeon x800 card. `glGetProgramInfoLog` reports:

```
Fragment shader(s) failed to link,  vertex shader(s) linked.
Fragment Shader not supported by HW
```

Some googling suggests that we may be hitting an ALU instruction limit, due to a very long fragment shader. Any way to verify that?

I wasn't able to find detailed specs for the x800, nor any way to query the instruction limit at runtime. And even if I was able to query it, how do I determine the number of instructions of my shader?

Answer (score 3):

There are several limits your may hit:

- maximum shader length
- maximum number of texture indirections (this is the limit most easily crossed)
- using unsupported features

Technically the X800 is a shader model 2 GPU, which as about what GLSL 1.20 provides. When I started shader programming with a Radeon 9800, and the X800 is just a upscaled 9800 technically, I quickly abandoned the idea of doing it with GLSL. It was just too limited. And like so often when computer has only limited resources and capabilites, the way out was using assembly. In that case I mean the assembly provided by ARB_fragment_program extension.

Comment: Indeed it is not possible to determine the instruction count startin from GLSL?

Answer (score 3):

[GLview](http://www.realtech-vr.com/glview/) is a great tool to easily view all the limitations and supported GL extensions of a GPU/driver combination. If I recall correctly, I previously used [AMD GPU ShaderAnalyzer](https://gpuopen.com/archive/gpu-shaderanalyzer/) which allows you to see the assembly compiled version of GLSL shaders. NVidia offers the same functionality with the nvemulate tool.

The x800 is very limited in shader power compared to current GPUs. You would probably have to cut back on your shader complexity anyway for this lower-end GPU to achieve proper performance. If you have your GLSL version running, simply choosing different fragment shaders for the X800 will probably be the most sensible approach.